# What is the use of private constructor in abstract class in c#?

Tags: c#, private-constructor

I face the below question in the interview.

> Q1.Can we have a private constructor in the abstract class?

**Answer-** Yes, I gave an answer we can have then he again ask why and what is the use of the private constructor.
I'm not able to answer to this cross-question. Can anybody explain this? with practically in c# will great help.

Comment: Well you know what `private` means right?  So think of why you might want to apply that to a constructor... What benefit(s) would you get?  What change of functionality would occur?

Comment: See [constructor chaining](https://www.google.com/search?q=constructor+chaining)

Comment: The constructor will always be executed when you instantiate derived classes. But since an abstract class _cannot_ be instantiated, there is no need for a _public_ constructor, hence you can and should make it protected or private.

Comment: @ maccettura, Yes I know if I create a private constructor then I'm not able to inherit that class into any class and not even create the object of that class . I give this answer but he just asked mi. Then What Is the Use and why we able to a private constructor in abstract class I also not able to get his question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can think of two uses:

Firstly, for chaining. You might have multiple protected constructors, but want to execute common code in all of them:

```cs
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo(string name) : this(name, 0)
    {
    }

    protected Foo(int value) : this("", value)
    {
    }

    private Foo(string name, int value)
    {
        // Do common things with name and value, maybe format them, etc
    }
}
```

The second use would be to make it so that the only possible derived classes would be *nested* classes, which have access to private members. I've used this before when I want to enforce a limited number of derived classes, with instances usually exposed via the base class

```cs
public abstract class Operation
{
    public static readonly Operation Add { get; } = new AddOperation();
    public static readonly Operation Subtract { get; } = new SubtractOperation();

    // Only nested classes can use this...
    private Operation()
    {
    }

    private class AddOperation : Operation
    {
        ...
    }

    private class SubtractOperation : Operation
    {
        ...
    }
}
```